# Send email using php mail functions takes long time to receive email

Tags: php, email

I am send email using php mail function.But it takes long time to receive to the user.It should receive with 10 minutes.how can i do that and why it is taking long time to receive more than 30 minutes its taking now.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the recipient is not the one to blame, sometimes it is due to the ISP. In our country, our ISP provider accepts lots of requests that the queue may pile up. This is when using the ISP provided SMTP server as a SMTP relay server.

Answer (score 0):

Also the PHP mail() function has a limit depending on you host or server (first a volume limit and then a limit preventing you to send X emails in a row).

Were I you, I would use third parties APIs, like SendGrid or MailChimp... (they also provide mail tracking, error reports, opting out...) and are quite easy to use.